# Firebase firestore security rule for collectionGroup query

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to query and filter a collectionGroup from the client doing this:

```
const document = doc(db, 'forums/foo');

const posts = await getDocs(
  query(
    collectionGroup(db, 'posts'),
    orderBy(documentId()),
    startAt(document.path),
    endAt(document.path + '\uf8ff')
  )
);
```

My auth [custom user claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) looks like this:

```
{ forumIds: ['foo'] }
```

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#collection_group_queries_and_security_rules) tells me to add the following security rule:

```
match /{path=**}/posts/{post} {
  allow read: if request.auth != null;
}
```

But this is a security breach as it means that anyone can read all of the `posts` collections. I only want the user to read the posts in its forums. Is there no better way to secure a collectionGroup query?

(1) I have tried:

```
match /{path=**}/posts/{post} {
  allow read: if path[1] in request.auth.token.forumIds;
}
```

but I get this error: `Variable  is not bound in path template. for 'list' @ L49`.

(2) I have also tried:

```
match /{path=**}/posts/{post} {
  allow read: if resource.__name__[4] in request.auth.token.forumIds;
}
```

but I get this error: `Property __name__ is undefined on object. for 'list' @ L49`.

I have also tried debugging the two previous security rules with [debug](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.debug) and both of them return `true`.

Comment: I'm unclear what your requirement is for security.  Your question asks "Is there no better way to secure a collectionGroup query?" but you're not saying how exactly you want to control access.  The documentation is telling you how to express a path match that applies to collection group queries, but it's up to you to figure out how you want to take that further.

Comment: Let's say I want users to only query `posts` that belongs to the `forums` collection

Comment: Seems like you don't want a collection group query at all then.  Just query the specific collection you want documents from.  Collection group queries are always going to pull from all collections with the same name.

Comment: You are right, sorry. I have updated the original post to give more context.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your stated requirements, you don't want a collection group query at all.  A collection group query intends to fetch all of the documents in all of the named collections.  You can only filter the results based on the contents of the document like you would any other query.

Since you have a list of forums that the user should be able to read, you should just query them each individually and combine the results in the app.  Security rules are not going to be able to filter them out for you because security rules are not filters.

See also:

- https://medium.com/firebase-developers/what-does-it-mean-that-firestore-security-rules-are-not-filters-68ec14f3d003
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters

Comment: Thanks. I understand that security rules are not filters but in my case the filtering is done in the query on the client side. This is the reason why I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: Your attempts at rules are pretty clearly trying to make the rule do the filtering, not the client.  That simply will never work - you can't have a rule limit the result set based on some condition.  The query will return either all of the documents matched by the query, or none of them if the rules would deny any of the matched documents.

Comment: In my case, none of the documents are denied by the rule but I still receive nothing.